# Python Convert BeautifulSoup Output to Set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, set

In python I have:

```
def tag_visible(element):
    return True


def get_visible_text(soup):
    text_tags = soup.find_all(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, text_tags)
    stripped = set()
    for text in visible_texts:
        stripped.add(text.strip())
    return stripped
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How to convert `visible_texts` into set in **one** line?
2. Is there a data structure in python like set (no duplicates) and preserves order of elements?

---

**UPDATE:**

I can do:

```
return set(visible_texts)
```

But how to apply strip `function`?

Comment: Please let me know if anything isn't clear, I'm looking for more efficient approach

Comment: Cause question / goal is not that clear, please provide additianl information (example of input and expected output) that deals with the issue you are faced. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict`s preserve insertion order. `dict`s contain key-value pairs. In this case, you don't care about the value, so it's always set to `True`.

I'm not too sure what you are trying to achieve by using `filter` with a function that always returns `True`. Please clarify.

```py
def get_visible_text(soup):
    text_tags = soup.find_all(text=True)
    return dict((text.strip(), True) for text in text_tags)
```

---

You can apply the strip function by using a [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```py
return set(text.strip() for text in visible_texts)
```

Note, however, that the insertion order is not necessarily preserved.